# Add messages (and not threads) with > 5 MB attachment to a Gmail label

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I want to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591868/1422096) to remove all attachments for certain emails which have > 5 MB attachment.

In order to do this, I first search, in the Gmail GUI, `has:attachment larger:5m`, and then I add these threads to a label `to_process`. Then I can run the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591868/1422096):

```
var emails = GmailApp.search('label:to_process'); 
for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    removeAttachment(...);
}
```

Problem: when there is a thread with 10 messages and only one of them has a > 5MB attachment, then all the messages of this thread will be in `to_process` label!

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798530/gmailapp-add-label-to-specific-message-not-the-thread) a method to only add messages and not threads to a label, but I still haven't found a solution for this:

**How to add all messages with a > 5 MB attachment to this label, but only the *messages*, without adding all the *thread*?**

Comment: The easiest way is to [Turn Off Conversation View](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900) in settings and run the script

Comment: @random-parts Good idea about "Conversation Mode off" but I can't find a way to [loop on messages (not threads) of a specific label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670565/looping-on-messages-not-threads-of-a-specific-gmail-label).