# Looping on messages (not threads) of a specific Gmail label

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I added specific *messages* (and not the whole *thread*) to a label `to_process` with these steps:

1. Turn `Conversation Mode` off in Gmail settings
2. Apply the label `to_process` to specific messages
3. When displaying the messages, I can confirm that only the specific *messages* have been added. **For example, another message which is in the same thread doesn't have this label**. This is good.

Now I'd like to loop on all these messages from Google Apps Script. But the problem is that the API can only give access to *threads* attached to a certain label:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:to_process'); 
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // problem: here I cannot access to messages but only threads
}
```

or

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("to_process");
var threads = label.getThreads();
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // problem: here I cannot access to messages but only threads       
}
```

**How to loop on messages (and not threads) associated to a label?**

---

Beginning of a solution but I don't know how to continue:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:to_process'); 
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var message = messages[j];

        // pseudo code here because getMessageLabels doesn't exist
        //if ("to_process" is in message.getMessageLabels()) {
        //}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with 
[Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) and the [Gmail API list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), then [getMessageById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessageById(String)) :

```
function listMessages () {
  // Only return messages matching the specified query.
  var msgs = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {'q':'label:to_process larger:5M'}).messages;

  // For each message - retrieve it by its id
  msgs.forEach(function (e){
    Logger.log("This email's subject is: %s", GmailApp.getMessageById(e.id).getSubject());
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what is the difference between `GmailApp.function()` and `Gmail.function()` @random-parts? Is it two different APIs? Oh I see the answer is in the link you provided: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail