# Google app Script delete specific attachment from gmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, email-attachments

I'm bit new to google app script and try figure out how to resolve my google mail problem with google app script

---

Update : only particular attachment need to  be remove rest of the structure and attachment need to same. provided solution remove all the attachments !

Problem :

I daily get email with pdf attachments from my vendors and clients some are send to me using automatic systems and some from manual some of this email has **attachment called "noname"** which I cant open or read. I'm using automated application to download this pdf attachments when there is "noname " attachment that email fully ignored so I miss some pdf daily

---

Planed Solution  :

using google app script I'm try to **capture the "noname" attachment and delete** only that file rest of the email content and pdf need to be same .

I have manage to implement code to capture specific email which send noname attachment and if they unread then check attachments and delete noname

---

Where I need advice : how to delete selected attachment ??

```
function myFunction() {

  Logger.log("unread emails: " +
             GmailApp.search('is:unread from:pdf_sender@gmail.com'));

  var deta = GmailApp.search('is:unread from:1031mymailx@gmail.com')

  var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(deta);

        for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
              Logger.log("msg object lenth " + msgs.length)

            for (var j = 0; j <  msgs.length; j++) {
                Logger.log("msg i object lenth " + msgs[i].length)
                var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
                var m_id = msgs[i][j].getId()

              for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
                  Logger.log("attachment lenth " +  attachments.length)
                  Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',  msgs[i][j].getSubject(), attachments[k].getName(), attachments[k].getSize());

                      if (attachments[k].getName() == "noname" ){

                     //  attachments[k].deleteAttachment();
                    Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',  msgs[i] 
                      [j].getSubject(), attachments[k].getName(),attachments[k].getSize());

              }       
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove an attachment of a Gmail email with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434390/remove-an-attachment-of-a-gmail-email-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Casper but it remove all the attachments. here I need to remove only noname attachment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMail messages are immutable - that is, you cannot modify them. However, you can re-create them by downloading their content, modifying it, and inserting the modified message back into your account.

I have modified your code so that it does what you asked for, using the method explained. It iterates over the search results and checks whether the message contains a filename called `noname`. In case it does, it inserts a modification of the original message that does not contain the `noname` attachment.

Additionally, you may opt to uncomment two different lines so that:

1. The new message gets inserted with `INBOX` label (so that it shows up in your inbox) and `UNREAD` labels.
2. The original message gets trashed after inserting the new one.

```js
var BOUNDARY_REGEX = new RegExp('boundary=\"(.+)\"');

function removeAttachment(msg) {
  var emailContent = msg.getRawContent();
  if (emailContent.indexOf('filename=noname') == -1) return;

  var boundary = BOUNDARY_REGEX.exec(emailContent)[1];
  var boundaryLine = '--' + boundary;

  var sections = emailContent.split(boundaryLine);

  var filteredSections = sections.filter(function(value, index, arr) {
    return value.indexOf('filename=noname') == -1;
  });

  var resultBody = filteredSections.join(boundaryLine);
  var encodedResultBody = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(resultBody);
  var resource = {'raw': encodedResultBody};
  // OPTIONAL - LABEL YOUR NEWLY CREATED MAIL AS 'INBOX' & 'UNREAD'
  // resource['labelIds'] = ['INBOX', 'UNREAD'];
  var response = Gmail.Users.Messages.insert(resource, 'me', null, {'internalDateSource': 'dateHeader'});
  Logger.log("Inserted email id is: %s", response.id);
  // OPTIONAL - TRASH ORIGINAL MESSAGE
  // GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(msg);
  return response.id;
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log("unread emails: " +
             GmailApp.search('is:unread from:pdf_sender@gmail.com'));

  var deta = GmailApp.search('is:unread from:1031mymailx@gmail.com')

  var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(deta);

  for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
      Logger.log("msg object length " + msgs[j].length);    
      removeAttachment(msgs[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Before executing this code, please make sure that you have the GMail Advanced service [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

Comment: Dear @carlesgg97  this help lot to me. I appreciate time & effort given for this answer 

after enable the advance services on first try I got issue with msg.getRawContent() .
then I resolve it adding https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata to the **metadata** then I get this error with Access denied: : Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter _line_ _ Logger.log("unread emails: " +
             GmailApp.search _
at the moment I'm stuck here

Comment: Hey @Darshanak, I assume that what you mean is that you added the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata` to your project. If I understood this correctly, then this is due to the `search()` method requiring less restrictive permissions. In order to execute every operation in the script you will need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify` scope (or if you still have issues with this one, then `https://mail.google.com/`). Let me know if that fixes your issue, Thanks.

Comment: Hi @carlesgg97  thanks for the advice and it resolve the issue . now there is a `TypeError: Cannot find function getRawContent in object GmailMessage.`

Comment: Hey @Darshanak, apologies. `GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads()` returns a 2D-list of Gmail messages. I have edited the answer above so that it doesn't throw that error. Kindly let me know should you have any other issue with it.

Comment: ok now I'm stuck here mate it say no regex define 
`var boundary = BOUNDARY_REGEX.exec(emailContent)[1];`
if I user manual regex then I stuck at 

`(function(value, index, arr)`

Comment: Hey @Darshanak kindly make sure the first line of my code, `var BOUNDARY_REGEX = new RegExp('boundary=\"(.+)\"');` is in your code too. Let me know if it works for you now. Cheers

Comment: @Darshanak would be nice to mark this answer as solution if it helped you